# SQLite Async Connection missing WithChildren Methods

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, sqlite-net-extensions

I have a Xamarin Forms project that uses SQLite. I have a parent and child Model 
with the correct Foreign Key, ManyToOne and Cascading options on relevant fields.

I have been using Scott Hanselman's AsyncLock class (http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ComparingTwoTechniquesInNETAsynchronousCoordinationPrimitives.aspx) 
in my db methods like this:

```
public async Task<List<Client>> GetAllAsync()
{
    List<Client> clients = new List<Client>();
    using (await SQLiteBase.Mutex.LockAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
    {
       //SQLiteAsyncConnection _connection is set up elsewhere...
        clients = await _sqLiteBase._connection.Table<Client>().ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }           

return clients;
}
```

No problem so far. The issue I am facing, is that I cannot see cascading actions on this connection. I added a normal `SQLiteConnection`, which had the -`WithChildren` methods, but I need to use the `SQLiteAsyncConnection` connection.

I have references to SQLite.Net, SQLiteNetExtensions, SQLite.Net.Async and SQLitePCL.raw.

Why can't I see the ~`WithChildren` methods on the async connection object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to add a SQLiteNetExtensions.Async package to your project https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLiteNetExtensions.Async/

Comment: @Daniel_Luberda Thank you, I was trying to figure out why having SQLiteNetExtensions was not allowing me to do the WithChildren calls. Your answer fixed it. Now I just have to figure out why the WithChildren calls dont return.

Comment: No problem. What do you mean exactly that they don't return? I think it may be related to ConfigureAwait(false)) which means that you don't need subsequent calls in the same thread context BUT I'm quite sure sqlite needs the same context for a connection and its methods.